# Iterate and compare one value with other

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a following XML data:

```
<Product>
  <item>
   <ProductVariant>
     <item>
        <VariantType>1</VariantType>
     </item>
     <item>
        <VariantType>2</VariantType>
     </item>
     <item>
        <VariantType>3</VariantType>
     </item>
   </ProductVariant>
   <ChosenVariantType>2</ChosenVariantType>
  </item>
</Product>
```

and than I have an xsl transformation:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Product/item/ProductVariant">
    <xsl:if test="(item/VariantType = ../ChosenVariantType)">
        <xsl:value-of name="test" select="item/VariantType"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of name="testChosen" select="../ChosenVariantType"/>
    </xsl:if>   
</xsl:for-each>
```

which prints out: 1-2

so the question is why 'if' evaluates as true if VariantType is 1 and ChosenVariantType is 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over **ProductVariant** of which there is only one in your XML. When you do your **xsl:if** condition, all you are testing is whether there is any **item** under the current **ProductVariant** with a matching **VariantType**. In your case, there is. But when you do the **xsl:value-of**, it will ouptut the value of the first **item**, whether it matches the variant type or not.

You could either change you **xsl:value-of** to this:

```
<xsl:value-of name="test" select="item[VariantType = ../ChosenVariantType]/VariantType"/>
```

(Although this is rather pointless because you know the VariantType matches ChosenVariantType).

Or maybe you need to iterate over **item** elements here?

```
<xsl:for-each select="Product/item/ProductVariant/item">
    <xsl:if test="(VariantType = ../../ChosenVariantType)">
        <xsl:value-of name="test" select="VariantType"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of name="testChosen" select="../../ChosenVariantType"/>
    </xsl:if>   
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: thnx a lot.. this is my second question here.. and you answered them both!